# Porque meu JavaScript com Class não funciona?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
        <title>JS 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                font-family: arial;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .BG_1 {
                height: 689px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            .BOX_BG_1 {
                width: 380px;
                height: 240px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                background-color: gray;
            }
            .MIN_BOX_BG_1 {
                width: 380px;
                height: 80px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 25px;
                line-height: 80px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .MSG_MIN_BOX_BG_1 {
                outline: 0px;
                border: 0px;
                width: 250px;
                height: 30px;
                background-color: white;
                padding-left-right: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .BOTAO_MIN_BOX_BG_1 {
                outline: 0px;
                border: 0px;
                height: 40px;
                width: 75px;
                color: green;
                background-color: yellow;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            .MIN_BOX_BG_1 {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "BG_1">
            <div class = "BOX_BG_1">
                <div class = "MIN_BOX_BG_1">
                    Calc Space
                </div>
                <div class = "MIN_BOX_BG_1">
                    <input class = "MSG_MIN_BOX_BG_1" placeholder = "Digite aqui sua idade!"/>
                </div>
                <div class = "MIN_BOX_BG_1">
                    <BUTTON class = "BOTAO_MIN_BOX_BG_1" onclick = "Resposta()">Enviar</BUTTON>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Resposta() {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName('MSG_MIN_BOX_BG_1').value;
                if(x <= 0) 
                    document.getElementsByClassName('MIN_BOX_BG_1').innerHTML = 'Não válido!';
                if(x>0)
                    document.getElementsByClassName('MIN_BOX_BG_1').innerHTML = 'Esse número é válido!';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que é que estás a tentar fazer?

Comment: Quero apenas validar um dado que o cliente irá por no INPUT como sendo válido ou não. Obg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `document.getElementsByClassName()` trás um vetor. Logo, você tem que acessar o elemento na posição desejada.

Segue o seu código corrigido. Observe os índices `[0]` utilizados para fazê-lo funcionar.

```js
function Resposta() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('MSG_MIN_BOX_BG_1')[0].value;
    if (x <= 0) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('MIN_BOX_BG_1')[0].innerHTML = 'Não válido!';
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('MIN_BOX_BG_1')[0].innerHTML = 'Esse número é válido!';
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: arial;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
.BG_1 {
    height: 689px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.BOX_BG_1 {
    width: 380px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
}
.MIN_BOX_BG_1 {
    width: 380px;
    height: 80px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
.MSG_MIN_BOX_BG_1 {
    outline: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-left-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.BOTAO_MIN_BOX_BG_1 {
    outline: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 75px;
    color: green;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.MIN_BOX_BG_1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "BG_1">
    <div class = "BOX_BG_1">
        <div class = "MIN_BOX_BG_1">
            Calc Space
        </div>
        <div class = "MIN_BOX_BG_1">
            <input class = "MSG_MIN_BOX_BG_1" placeholder = "Digite aqui sua idade!"/>
        </div>
        <div class = "MIN_BOX_BG_1">
            <BUTTON class = "BOTAO_MIN_BOX_BG_1" onclick = "Resposta()">Enviar</BUTTON>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Para testar, você pode clicar no botão azul "Executar" acima e clicar no link para ver em "Página toda".

Answer (score 0):

O erro está no método **getElementsByClassName**.

O **getElementsByClassName** retorna um vetor de objetos com todos os elementos filhos que possuem o nome da classe dada.  Quando invocado no objeto document, o documento é examinado por completo, incluindo o nó raiz. Você também pode invocar getElementsByClassName() em qualquer elemento; isso retornaria somente elementos que são descendentes do nó raiz especificado com o nome da classe.

Ref.:https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName